# Twitter api - is it possible to post a thread?

Tags: php, twitter, bots

I have a Twitter bot that posts short bits of text that are sometimes over the character limit for one tweet. When it is over the limit I would like to have the bot post the full text as several tweets organized as a thread. I don't see any documentation in their API docs for doing this. Any ideas for how to accomplish this?

My bot is written in PHP and uses this class:
https://github.com/J7mbo/twitter-api-php

Answer (score 1):

It may not (ever?) be available, per this thread: [Is there any api update for tweet thread(storm) feature which recently released in twitter?](https://twittercommunity.com/t/is-there-any-api-update-for-tweet-thread-storm-feature-which-recently-released-in-twitter/98538)

I've done several Google searches on the topic and have not found a single article that shows how to use the API to create multi-tweet threads. Similar searches in the [API documentation](https://developer.twitter.com/en.html) turned up nothing. I have so many good ideas for how to make use of such a feature, which is probably why it doesn't exist...it also has too much potential for abuse.

Comment: Hey I don't know if you are still working with this but a thread is basically a tweet with replies, twitter lets you reply to a status as long as you have the status ID, have you tried just send a single tweet capturing the ID and continuing with that pattern till your thread is complete?

Comment: The link you posted here to the Twitter forum does not say that the feature will never be available - it says it is already available! You simply respond to each sequential Tweet with a new status post replying to the previous status ID.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a thread using `reply`.
Here is the example on java
https://gist.github.com/ivamluz/6284531#file-twitter4j-post-reply-java

```
public static void replyTo(List<Status> tweets) {
    Twitter twitter = new TwitterFactory().getInstance();

    Status reply = null;
    for (Status tweet : tweets) {
        try {
            reply = twitter.updateStatus(new StatusUpdate(UUID.randomUUID() +  " - @" + tweet.getUser().getScreenName() + " this is a reply to your tweet.").inReplyToStatusId(tweet.getId()));

            System.out.println("Posted reply " + reply.getId() + " in response to tweet " + reply.getInReplyToStatusId());
        } catch (TwitterException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } 
    }
}
```

Comment: When linking something please add an extract of the essential part of the linked page. This way the reply will still be useful even if the link would become broken

Comment: I thing the OP was asking about [this kind of thread](https://help.twitter.com/en/using-twitter/create-a-thread), not a replyTo thread.

Answer (score 1):

Just found out that twitter api does support tweeting thread. 
I'm using typscript, and this is the library that I'm using.
https://github.com/PLhery/node-twitter-api-v2/blob/53b0daf4b34fe158e12bd20038981938cc092085/doc/v2.md#Postathreadoftweets 
For official api, here's the link:
https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/tutorials/determining-tweet-types

> A user can reply to themselves in the case of a "thread" – a series of connected Tweets from one person (How to create a thread on Twitter).